# SVN permissions, one group with rw and one user in group with r

Tags: linux, svn, permissions

I want to make a group, for example, "testGroup" and I have 3 users in this group, user1 and user2 and user3.

On a repository, I want user1, user2 have read/write permissions but user3 have only read permission.
I try that ... but it don't work ...

```
 [groups]
 group = user1, user2, user3

 [test:/]
 @group = rw
 user3 = r
```

Is it possible without write user1, user2 in [test:/] ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible without write user1, user2 in [test:/] ?

Yes, but only if you'll have second group (without user3) in repo-ACL. In your case group's permissions overload personal